# System.Drawing.Common not working on Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitmap, system.drawing

I'm trying to run a simple C# Application on windows 11. I'm using the System.Drawing to edit a png file, but this error is occuring.

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform.'

After a bit of research, turns out System.Drawing is only supported on windows.. but I am using windows.. Perhaps it's because I'm using windows 11?

Furthermore, adding

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport", true);
```

Didn't seem to fix this issue either

The error is thrown on this line of code:

```cs
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(file));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must build your project for windows. You do this by adding `-windows` to your current [Target Framework Moniker (TFM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)  in the project file:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This tells the compiler that you will be running your application exclusively on windows.

If you are using winforms, also add

```xml
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```